# How to update/transfer into accounts from opportunities

Tags: custom-object

I need custom fields that are in my opportunities to be in my accounts. I don't care if they're copied, a relationship is setup, or they're actually moved. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First question: If Field A is on Opp 1 and Opp 2 related to Account A. If the value in Field A is different on the Opps, how do you determine who wins.

After that, the best way to do it is a data export and then move the fields to the account, updating as required.